# Black around text input when hover it

Tags: html, css, input

When i hover the text input(textbox), a black thing goes visible, around the textbox.
Here's how it looks like:

[image: http://gyazo.com/cac41a95bbb251c426a3657552c2d146]

Do anyone know how to fix it?
First i had a button, it happend the same thing when i had the button.
Could it be something with the PHP?

CSS:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    margin:auto;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 32px;
}

#top {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#logo {
    clear:left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    height:60px;
}

#nav {
    clear:right;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 0px;
    float:right;
    height:60px;
}

#content
{
    width:97.9%;
    min-height:400px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding:20px;
}

#footer {
    height:100px;

}

.divider1 {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 8px auto;
   height: 0;
   width: 90%;
   max-height: 0;
   font-size: 1px;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
   border: none;
   border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.bp {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 60%;
}

/* Navigation Menu
---------------------------------*/

ul ul {
display: none;
background: #00B6ED;
}
ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
ul {
background: #00B6ED;
border-radius: 2px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: -25px;
margin-left: -8px;
}
ul:after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: block;
}
ul li {
float: left;
}
ul li:hover {
background: #404040;
}
ul li:hover a {
color: #fff;
}
ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 5px;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
height: 25px;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
ul ul { /* Hover menu */
background: #6B6B6B;
border-radius: 0px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}

ul ul li {
float: none;
border-top: 1px solid #6B6B6B;
position: relative;
}
ul ul li a {
color: #fff;
height: 30px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
ul ul li a:hover {
background: #404040;
height: 30px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
height: 35px;
top: 0;
}
.js-enabled ul li:hover > ul {
display: none;
}

.menu-hover {
margin-left: 0px;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#query {
    background: #FFF url("http://tutorialnom.grn.cc/sicon.png") no-repeat scroll 3px 2px;
    margin-left: 63%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font-size: 15px;
    outline:0; 
    padding-left: 25px;
    height:25px; 
    width: 275px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
$('.menu-hover').jVanilla({
speed   : 10, //  the speed of animations
animation   : 'sliding', // sliding or fading
eventType   : 'hover', // hover or click
delay   : 100, // the delay time on mouseout
isHoverClickable: true, // set to true if you want to enable the click on the first level link
isLastRightAlign: true // set to false if you want to align left the last submenu 
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="nav">
<nav>
<ul class="menu-hover">
<li> <a href="index.php"> Home </a> </li>
<li> <a href="downloads.php" id="dd"> Downloads </a>
<ul>
<li><a href="paddis-skypetools.php">Paddis SkypeTools</a></li>
<li><a href="greatzip.php">GreatZip</a></a></li>
<li><a href="pczip-cleaner.php">Pc Zip Cleaner</a></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="forums.php"> Forums </a></li>
<li> <a href="youtube.php"> YouTube </a> </li>
<li> <a href="contact.php"> Contact </a>

<li>

<form class="searchForm" action="search.php" method="GET">
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="q" id="query" class="shape-search" />
     <div>
      <!-- <button class="shape-search">Q</button> -->
     </div>
     </form>

</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your screenshot isn't showing anything. Might be better to post a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Yes, it shows the black thingy?!

Comment: I added an answer and a working demo below.

Comment: It's your code... how can you not know how you made it do this in the first place?  It's strange because typically people ask how something is done, not how to undo something.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `hover` attribute on your `<li>` tags in the CSS. Because you have the form as a list item, it's also giving a background color change when you hover over it.

Remove (or comment out)

```
ul li:hover {
background: #404040;
}
```

And then change this on the next line:

```
ul li:hover a {
color: #404040;  /* the color was #fff */
}
```

Here's a [working demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/tAEnL).

Comment: In the demo linked, or on your site? If you mean in the demo, I don't have the correct file paths in the `href`, so they don't work. Or, do you mean the hover attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have this class of `hover`

```
ul li:hover {
   background: #404040;
}
```

and a `margin-top` of `15px` which allows the `black` color to be visible. Replace your **CSS** of `query` class with this:

```
#query
{
    background: #FFF url("http://tutorialnom.grn.cc/sicon.png") no-repeat scroll 3px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font-size: 15px;
    outline:0; 
    padding-left: 25px;
    height:25px; 
    width: 275px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

You need to set `positioned:fix` and remove the `margin-left`

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IFhae)**